# jQuery trigger click after changing url

Tags: html, jquery

I have a function that records clicks on a link with a data tag. The code hides a telephone number until the link has been clicked, then it reveals the number. The problem I'm having is I am unable to get that revealed number to fire without user interaction once it has loaded.

I had to prevent the default event for when the button is clicked for the first time as the url does not yet contain the real data and also I don't want the page to jump.

Once clicked the new link's html will change to, example: "☎ 0123456789"
and the href will change to, example: "tel:0123456789"
This data is obtained from JSON sent from AJAX PHP file.

After this I want to programatically click the URL but I can't seem to get it to fire and keep getting a console error message saying "Uncaught TypeError: event is undefined"
 ~ *presumably to do with the event prevent default?*

**Info:** there will be multiple phone numbers loaded via PHP so I need to access each one individually.

**HTML for the link;**

```
 <a data-num='$number' class='telephone' href='#'>&#9742; Click to call</a>
```

**JS code (jQuery 3.4.1);**

```
 $(document).on('click','.telephone',function(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); // Prevent page jump
     var num = $(this).data("num");
     $.ajax({
         url: "myserverfile.php",
         method: "POST",
         data: {num: num},
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(a) {
             var b = (a[0]['status']); // True or false
             var c = (a[0]['tel']); // Number or error
             // If result found change URL and click it to call number
             if (b == true) {
                 $('.telephone[data-num="' + num + '"]').html("&#9742;&nbsp;" + c); // Change link text
                 $('.telephone[data-num="' + num + '"]').attr("href", "tel:" + c); // Change link href
                 $('.telephone[data-num="' + num +'"]').click(); // Update: This causes a loop because it runs the code again. I need to hide the original a tag and create a new one then trigger it.
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error message? What is value of `num`?

Comment: num is a column from a row on a table which also contains another column with the telephone number. The error references 4 parts of the code, the first one is the event.preventDefault(); so I'm thinking that's the issue as the rest of the references are okay.

Comment: `event is undefined is coming from something not shown...probably the click event listener code

Comment: num in this case is "5f4284e4ce801" which identifies the specific row. All of this is working except for the auto click after the URL has been changed via jQuery.

Comment: Show us the code that listens to the click event .... seems you forgot to add the event argument to the handler function before calling event.preventDefault inside it

Comment: Yes, the first error says it's the event.preventDefault(); causing an issue but I don't know how to get around that. I tried using return false; and later return true then click but that causes even more issues.

Comment: Ah I get you now. It's weird that it still works though. Let me do a test, I'll be back.

Comment: You simply forgot to include the event argument...98% sure on that without seeing code

Comment: I changed the code, all errors have gone, thanks :) but still not firing the link due to the event.preventDefault(); Stack Overflow is warning me to avoid extended discussions. Still stuck.

Comment: Well that's a different issue we can't see any code for. Probably not delegating the event listener is my bet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221756/discussion-between-sjacks-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was creating a loop so the click wouldn't work so I hid the first link after the click and loaded a new hidden one. I used a different column value from the table for the data tag on this new link to avoid any possible conflicts.

Apart from the loop issue the major part I was missing was [0] before assigning .click.

Thanks for the suggestions along the way.

**Working code below;**

```
 $(document).on('click', '.telephone', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var num = $(this).data("num");

     $.ajax({
         url: "myserverfile.php",
         method: "POST",
         data: {num: num},
         dataType: "json",

         success: function(a) {
             var b = (a[0]['status']);
             var c = (a[0]['id']);
             var d = (a[0]['tel']);

             if (b == true) {
                 $('.telephone[data-num="' + num + '"]').hide(200);
                 $(document).ready(function() {
                     $(".telephone-reveal");
                     $('.telephone-reveal[data-id="' + c + '"]').show(200);
                     $('.telephone-reveal[data-id="' + c + '"]').html("&#9742;&nbsp;" + d);
                     $('.telephone-reveal[data-id="' + c + '"]').attr("href", "tel:" + d);
                     $('.telephone-reveal[data-id="' + c + '"]')[0].click();
                 });
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `.click()` method doesn't create an `event`. The `event` is created when the user actually clicks something. If you `console.log(event)` it'll be `undefined` when called by `.click()`, which is where you're getting the error from. To get around that you could

```
if (event) { event.preventDefault(); }
```

But then you're going to run into recursion since you're basically

```
$(document).on('click', '.telephone', function() { $('.telephone').click(); });
```

To get around that you could add something like a `loaded` class

```
$(document).on('click', '.telephone:not(.loaded)', function() {
  $('.telephone[data-num="' + num +'"]')
    .addClass('loaded')
    .attr(...)
    .html(...)
    .click();
});
```

Also, you'll thank yourself later for using a little more descriptive variable names. And for those unaware, [jquery is chainable](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp).